# OpenGL SL barrel distortion: what's wrong with this SDL2 code

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, sdl-2

**UPDATE**

Ok, I read [Learn OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/book/book_pdf.pdf) book from https://learnopengl.com/ and changed the OP code in order to support OpenGL 3.3 and later. I don't have the time now for writing the complete solution but if someone is interested ask!

**OLD OP**

I wrote an emulator using SDL2 and what I want is to add a barrel distortion, like an old CRT, to final rectangular video frame texture.

OpenGL SL vertex and fragment shaders come from [here](https://www.geeks3d.com/20140213/glsl-shader-library-fish-eye-and-dome-and-barrel-distortion-post-processing-filters/2/).

This is the code, icon.bmp is [here](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/raw/main/test/icon.bmp):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_opengl.h"

static SDL_bool shaders_supported;
static int current_shader = 0;

enum
{
    SHADER_1,
    SHADER_2,
    NUM_SHADERS
};

typedef struct
{
    GLhandleARB program;
    GLhandleARB vert_shader;
    GLhandleARB frag_shader;
    const char *vert_source;
    const char *frag_source;
} ShaderData;

static ShaderData shaders[NUM_SHADERS] =
{
// SHADER_1
        {0, 0, 0,
/* vertex shader */
"varying vec4 v_color;\n"
"varying vec2 v_texCoord;\n"
"\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;\n"
"    v_color = gl_Color;\n"
"    v_texCoord = vec2(gl_MultiTexCoord0);\n"
"}",

/* fragment shader */
"varying vec4 v_color;\n"
"varying vec2 v_texCoord;\n"
"uniform sampler2D tex0;\n"
"\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex0, v_texCoord) * v_color;\n"
"}"
        },

// SHADER_2
        {0, 0, 0,
/* vertex shader */
"varying vec4 Vertex_UV;\n"
"uniform mat4 gxl3d_ModelViewProjectionMatrix;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"  gl_Position = gxl3d_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;\n"
"  Vertex_UV = gl_MultiTexCoord0;\n"
"}",

/* fragment shader */
"uniform sampler2D tex0;\n"
"varying vec4 Vertex_UV;\n"
"const float PI = 3.1415926535;\n"
"uniform float BarrelPower;\n"
"\n"
"vec2 Distort(vec2 p)\n"
"{\n"
"    float theta  = atan(p.y, p.x);\n"
"    float radius = length(p);\n"
"    radius = pow(radius, BarrelPower);\n"
"    p.x = radius * cos(theta);\n"
"    p.y = radius * sin(theta);\n"
"    return 0.5 * (p + 1.0);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"  vec2 xy = 2.0 * Vertex_UV.xy - 1.0;\n"
"  vec2 uv;\n"
"  float d = length(xy);\n"
"  if (d < 1.0)\n"
"  {\n"
"    uv = Distort(xy);\n"
"  }\n"
"  else\n"
"  {\n"
"    uv = Vertex_UV.xy;\n"
"  }\n"
"  vec4 c = texture2D(tex0, uv);\n"
"  gl_FragColor = c;\n"
"}"
        }
};

static PFNGLATTACHOBJECTARBPROC glAttachObjectARB;
static PFNGLCOMPILESHADERARBPROC glCompileShaderARB;
static PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMOBJECTARBPROC glCreateProgramObjectARB;
static PFNGLCREATESHADEROBJECTARBPROC glCreateShaderObjectARB;
static PFNGLDELETEOBJECTARBPROC glDeleteObjectARB;
static PFNGLGETINFOLOGARBPROC glGetInfoLogARB;
static PFNGLGETOBJECTPARAMETERIVARBPROC glGetObjectParameterivARB;
static PFNGLGETUNIFORMLOCATIONARBPROC glGetUniformLocationARB;
static PFNGLLINKPROGRAMARBPROC glLinkProgramARB;
static PFNGLSHADERSOURCEARBPROC glShaderSourceARB;
static PFNGLUNIFORM1IARBPROC glUniform1iARB;
static PFNGLUSEPROGRAMOBJECTARBPROC glUseProgramObjectARB;

static SDL_bool CompileShader(GLhandleARB shader, const char *source)
{
    GLint status = 0;

    glShaderSourceARB(shader, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShaderARB(shader);
    glGetObjectParameterivARB(shader, GL_OBJECT_COMPILE_STATUS_ARB, &status);

    if (status == 0)
    {
        GLint length = 0;
        char *info;

        glGetObjectParameterivARB(shader, GL_OBJECT_INFO_LOG_LENGTH_ARB, &length);
        info = (char *)SDL_malloc(length + 1);

        if (!info)
        {
            SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Out of memory!");
        }
        else
        {
            glGetInfoLogARB(shader, length, NULL, info);
            SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Failed to compile shader:\n%s\n%s", source, info);
            SDL_free(info);
        }

        return SDL_FALSE;

    }
    else
        return SDL_TRUE;
}

static SDL_bool LinkProgram(ShaderData *data)
{
    GLint status = 0;

    glAttachObjectARB(data->program, data->vert_shader);
    glAttachObjectARB(data->program, data->frag_shader);
    glLinkProgramARB(data->program);

    glGetObjectParameterivARB(data->program, GL_OBJECT_LINK_STATUS_ARB, &status);
    if (status == 0)
    {
        GLint length = 0;
        char *info;

        glGetObjectParameterivARB(data->program, GL_OBJECT_INFO_LOG_LENGTH_ARB, &length);
        info = (char *) SDL_malloc(length + 1);

        if (!info)
            SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Out of memory!");
        else
        {
            glGetInfoLogARB(data->program, length, NULL, info);
            SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Failed to link program:\n%s", info);
            SDL_free(info);
        }

        return SDL_FALSE;

    }
    else
        return SDL_TRUE;
}

static SDL_bool CompileShaderProgram(ShaderData *data)
{
    const int num_tmus_bound = 4;
    int i;
    GLint location;

    glGetError();

    /* Create one program object to rule them all */
    data->program = glCreateProgramObjectARB();

    /* Create the vertex shader */
    data->vert_shader = glCreateShaderObjectARB(GL_VERTEX_SHADER_ARB);
    if (!CompileShader(data->vert_shader, data->vert_source))
        return SDL_FALSE;

    /* Create the fragment shader */
    data->frag_shader = glCreateShaderObjectARB(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_ARB);
    if (!CompileShader(data->frag_shader, data->frag_source))
        return SDL_FALSE;

    /* ... and in the darkness bind them */
    if (!LinkProgram(data))
        return SDL_FALSE;

    /* Set up some uniform variables */
    glUseProgramObjectARB(data->program);
    for (i = 0; i < num_tmus_bound; ++i)
    {
        char tex_name[5];
        SDL_snprintf(tex_name, SDL_arraysize(tex_name), "tex%d", i);
        location = glGetUniformLocationARB(data->program, tex_name);

        if (location >= 0)
            glUniform1iARB(location, i);
    }

    glUseProgramObjectARB(0);

    return (glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR) ? SDL_TRUE : SDL_FALSE;
}

static void DestroyShaderProgram(ShaderData *data)
{
    if (shaders_supported)
    {
        glDeleteObjectARB(data->vert_shader);
        glDeleteObjectARB(data->frag_shader);
        glDeleteObjectARB(data->program);
    }
}

static SDL_bool InitShaders()
{
    int i;

    /* Check for shader support */
    shaders_supported = SDL_FALSE;
    if (SDL_GL_ExtensionSupported("GL_ARB_shader_objects") &&
        SDL_GL_ExtensionSupported("GL_ARB_shading_language_100") &&
        SDL_GL_ExtensionSupported("GL_ARB_vertex_shader") &&
        SDL_GL_ExtensionSupported("GL_ARB_fragment_shader"))

    {
        glAttachObjectARB = (PFNGLATTACHOBJECTARBPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glAttachObjectARB");
        glCompileShaderARB = (PFNGLCOMPILESHADERARBPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glCompileShaderARB");
        glCreateProgramObjectARB = (PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMOBJECTARBPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glCreateProgramObjectARB");
        glCreateShaderObjectARB = (PFNGLCREATESHADEROBJECTARBPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glCreateShaderObjectARB");
        glDeleteObjectARB = (PFNGLDELETEOBJECTARBPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glDeleteObjectARB");
        glGetInfoLogARB = (PFNGLGETINFOLOGARBPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glGetInfoLogARB");
        glGetObjectParameterivARB = (PFNGLGETOBJECTPARAMETERIVARBPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glGetObjectParameterivARB");
        glGetUniformLocationARB = (PFNGLGETUNIFORMLOCATIONARBPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glGetUniformLocationARB");
        glLinkProgramARB = (PFNGLLINKPROGRAMARBPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glLinkProgramARB");
        glShaderSourceARB = (PFNGLSHADERSOURCEARBPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glShaderSourceARB");
        glUniform1iARB = (PFNGLUNIFORM1IARBPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glUniform1iARB");
        glUseProgramObjectARB = (PFNGLUSEPROGRAMOBJECTARBPROC) SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glUseProgramObjectARB");

        if (glAttachObjectARB && glCompileShaderARB && glCreateProgramObjectARB && glCreateShaderObjectARB &&
            glDeleteObjectARB && glGetInfoLogARB && glGetObjectParameterivARB && glGetUniformLocationARB &&
            glLinkProgramARB && glShaderSourceARB && glUniform1iARB && glUseProgramObjectARB)

            shaders_supported = SDL_TRUE;

    }

    if (!shaders_supported)
        return SDL_FALSE;

    /* Compile all the shaders */
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_SHADERS; ++i)
    {
        if (!CompileShaderProgram(&shaders[i]))
        {
            SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Unable to compile shader!\n");
            return SDL_FALSE;
        }
    }

    /* We're done! */
    return SDL_TRUE;
}

static void QuitShaders()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_SHADERS; ++i)
        DestroyShaderProgram(&shaders[i]);
}

/* Quick utility function for texture creation */
static int power_of_two(int input)
{
    int value = 1;

    while (value < input)
        value <<= 1;

    return value;
}

GLuint
SDL_GL_LoadTexture(SDL_Surface * surface, GLfloat * texcoord)
{
    GLuint texture;
    int w, h;
    SDL_Surface *image;
    SDL_Rect area;
    SDL_BlendMode saved_mode;

    /* Use the surface width and height expanded to powers of 2 */
    w = power_of_two(surface->w);
    h = power_of_two(surface->h);
    texcoord[0] = 0.0f;         /* Min X */
    texcoord[1] = 0.0f;         /* Min Y */
    texcoord[2] = (GLfloat) surface->w / w;     /* Max X */
    texcoord[3] = (GLfloat) surface->h / h;     /* Max Y */

    image = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, w, h, 32,
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_LIL_ENDIAN     /* OpenGL RGBA masks */
                                 0x000000FF,
                                 0x0000FF00,
                                 0x00FF0000,
                                 0xFF000000
#else
                                 0xFF000000,
                                 0x00FF0000,
                                 0x0000FF00,
                                 0x000000FF
#endif
        );

    if (image == NULL)
        return 1;

    /* Save the alpha blending attributes */
    SDL_GetSurfaceBlendMode(surface, &saved_mode);
    SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(surface, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);

    /* Copy the surface into the GL texture image */
    area.x = 0;
    area.y = 0;
    area.w = surface->w;
    area.h = surface->h;
    SDL_BlitSurface(surface, &area, image, &area);

    /* Restore the alpha blending attributes */
    SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(surface, saved_mode);

    /* Create an OpenGL texture for the image */
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                 0,
                 GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels);

    SDL_FreeSurface(image);     /* No longer needed */

    return texture;
}

/* A general OpenGL initialization function.    Sets all of the initial parameters. */
void InitGL(int Width, int Height)                    /* We call this right after our OpenGL window is created. */
{
    GLdouble aspect;

    glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);        /* This Will Clear The Background Color To Black */
    glClearDepth(1.0);                /* Enables Clearing Of The Depth Buffer */
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);                /* The Type Of Depth Test To Do */
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);            /* Enables Depth Testing */
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);            /* Enables Smooth Color Shading */

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();                /* Reset The Projection Matrix */

    aspect = (GLdouble)Width / Height;
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0 / aspect, 1.0 / aspect, 0.0, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

/* The main drawing function. */
void DrawGLScene(SDL_Window *window, GLuint texture, GLfloat * texcoord)
{
    /* Texture coordinate lookup, to make it simple */
    enum
    {
        MINX,
        MINY,
        MAXX,
        MAXY
    };

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);        /* Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer */
    glLoadIdentity();                /* Reset The View */

    /* Enable blending */
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    /* draw a textured square (quadrilateral) */
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    if (shaders_supported)
        glUseProgramObjectARB(shaders[current_shader].program);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);                /* start drawing a polygon (4 sided) */
    glTexCoord2f(texcoord[MINX], texcoord[MINY]);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);        /* Top Left */
    glTexCoord2f(texcoord[MAXX], texcoord[MINY]);
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);        /* Top Right */
    glTexCoord2f(texcoord[MAXX], texcoord[MAXY]);
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);        /* Bottom Right */
    glTexCoord2f(texcoord[MINX], texcoord[MAXY]);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);        /* Bottom Left */
    glEnd();                    /* done with the polygon */

    if (shaders_supported)
        glUseProgramObjectARB(0);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    /* swap buffers to display, since we're double buffered. */
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int done;
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Surface *surface;
    GLuint texture;
    GLfloat texcoords[4];

    /* Enable standard application logging */
    SDL_LogSetPriority(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, SDL_LOG_PRIORITY_INFO);

    /* Initialize SDL for video output */
    if ( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 )
    {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Unable to initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Create a 500x500 OpenGL screen */
    window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Shader Demo", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL );
    if ( !window )
    {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Unable to create OpenGL window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(2);
    }

    if ( !SDL_GL_CreateContext(window))
    {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Unable to create OpenGL context: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(3);
    }

    printf("Vendor graphic card: %s\n", glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
    printf("Renderer: %s\n", glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
    printf("Version GL: %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    printf("Version GLSL: %s\n", glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));

    surface = SDL_LoadBMP("icon.bmp");
    if ( ! surface )
    {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Unable to load icon.bmp: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(4);
    }

    texture = SDL_GL_LoadTexture(surface, texcoords);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    /* Loop, drawing and checking events */
    InitGL(500, 500);
    if (InitShaders())
        SDL_Log("Shaders supported, press SPACE to cycle them.\n");
    else
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Shaders not supported!\n");

    done = 0;
    while ( ! done )
    {
        DrawGLScene(window, texture, texcoords);

        /* This could go in a separate function */
        { SDL_Event event;
            while ( SDL_PollEvent(&event) )
            {
                if ( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
                    done = 1;

                if ( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
                {
                    if ( event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_SPACE )
                        current_shader = (current_shader + 1) % NUM_SHADERS;

                    if ( event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE )
                        done = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    QuitShaders();

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see when you press SPACE on keyboard the second shader shows a black window. I tried many barrel/fish eye shaders from internet but I always got the same behaviour, so something is wrong in this code.

I used to develop with SDL2 so I know only the theory behind OpenGL SL and I don't want to learn all OpenGL.

Really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Where do you set values for the non-`sampler2D` uniforms in `SHADER_2` like `gxl3d_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` or `BarrelPower`?

Comment: Spektre, you are very unfriendly. In the OP there is a complete code. I have input.bmp as texture, the first shader works, the second one doesn't and for sure is related to genpfault's question... BUT I don't know anything about OpenGL SL so, instead of ask to me WHERE I defined gxl3d_ModelViewProjectionMatrix or BarrelPower he could defines those variables adjusting my code. What I want is that the second shader deforms input.bmp, If I had known how to do it I would not have asked

Answer (score 1):

So the source you've used is not using modern OpenGL as you've noted. I've taken it as an example and nabbed some of your code to get a basic version working with modern OpenGL which I believe has the effect you're looking for. Note that I've used [GLEW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/) to write my version so I can get access to all the OpenGL functions.

Here is what happens when you press the spacebar in my version. I have the BarrelPower set at 2 as a constant in my shader, but you can play around with that value to inspect the results. You could also quite easily pass it in as an attribute for better configurability.

[image: Barrel Distortion Example]

Below is my source code which I have commented up to explain the changes. I figure that's better than listing them here since you can take a local copy and study it. Between this and LearnOpenGL.com it should be enough to get you up and running.

Let me know if this helps!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 640
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 480
#define NUM_SHADERS 2

// Some globals since this is an example
SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_GLContext glContext;

// Vertices (and texture coords) and indices
// See "SetupDrawing" function for their initialisation
float vertices[20];
int indices[6];

// Handles for out VBO and IBO
int vbo = -1;
int ibo = -1;

// Existing shader structure (unchanged)
typedef struct
{
    GLhandleARB program;
    GLhandleARB vert_shader;
    GLhandleARB frag_shader;
    const char* vert_source;
    const char* frag_source;
} ShaderData;

// Array of shaders - see comments for updates
static ShaderData shaders[NUM_SHADERS] =
{
    // SHADER_1
            {0, 0, 0,
            /* vertex shader - In our basic vertex shader you can see we take
            * position and textureCoord attributes. These are setup from our
            * global vertices array later in the code. You can also see that
            * we are passing out a textureCoord value which is picked up by
            * the fragment shader later on in the pipeline
            */
            "#version 330\n"
            "attribute vec3 position;\n"
            "attribute vec2 texCoord;\n"
            "out vec2 textureCoord;\n"
            "\n"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);\n"
            "   textureCoord = texCoord;\n"
            "}",

    /* fragment shader - Our fragment shader is very basic. It gets texture
    coords passed through our vertex shader and a texture. We then use the
    glsl texture function to perform our texturing. When you initially run 
    the app, this is the fragment shader that will be in use
    */
    "#version 330\n"
    "in vec2 textureCoord;\n"
    "uniform sampler2D theTexture;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "    gl_FragColor = texture(theTexture, textureCoord);\n"
    "}"
            },

    // SHADER_2
            {0, 0, 0,
    /* vertex shader - Our vertex shader remains unchanged for the second program. 
    The barrel distortion effect is being applied in the fragment shader only
    */
            "#version 330\n"
            "attribute vec3 position;\n"
            "attribute vec2 texCoord;\n"
            "out vec2 textureCoord;\n"
            "\n"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);\n"
            "   textureCoord = texCoord;\n"
            "}",

    /* fragment shader - Here is the barrel distortion fragment shader. Not
    too much has changed here. The updates are simply to the expected inputs
    which are the same as our basic fragment shader. Barrel power has been 
    made constant for simplicity. You can increase and decrease this value to
    observe the effects. In the main the code is essentially the same, I've 
    just changed the Vertex_UV.xy to textureCoord since that's what would've
    been in the Vertex_UV.x and .y variables in the old version. */
    "#version 330\n"
    "in vec2 textureCoord;\n"
    "uniform sampler2D theTexture;\n"
    "const float PI = 3.1415926535;\n"
    "const float BarrelPower = 2.0;\n"
    "\n"
    "vec2 Distort(vec2 p)\n"
    "{\n"
    "    float theta  = atan(p.y, p.x);\n"
    "    float radius = length(p);\n"
    "    radius = pow(radius, BarrelPower);\n"
    "    p.x = radius * cos(theta);\n"
    "    p.y = radius * sin(theta);\n"
    "    return 0.5 * (p + 1.0);\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "  vec2 xy = 2.0 * textureCoord - 1.0;\n"
    "  vec2 uv;\n"
    "  float d = length(xy);\n"
    "  if (d < 1.0)\n"
    "  {\n"
    "    uv = Distort(xy);\n"
    "  }\n"
    "  else\n"
    "  {\n"
    "    uv = textureCoord;\n"
    "  }\n"
    "  vec4 c = texture2D(theTexture, uv);\n"
    "  gl_FragColor = c;\n"
    "}"
            }
};

bool Setup()
{
    bool setupSuccess = false;

    bool sdlInitialised = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS) == 0;
    if (sdlInitialised)
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Barrel Distortion Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
        if (window)
        {
            glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
            glewInit();

            glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
            glClearColor(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 0.f);
            setupSuccess = true;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Could not initialise GL window\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Could not initialise SDL\n");
    }
    return setupSuccess;
}

void Teardown()
{
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ibo);
}

void SetupDrawing()
{
    // Setup vertices and texture coords. We setup a stride later for indexing these. The
    // first three values on each line are the vertices, the last two are the texture 
    // coordinates (U, V)
    vertices[0] = 1.0f;     vertices[1] = 1.0f;     vertices[2] = 0.0f;     vertices[3] = 0.f;      vertices[4] = 0.f;
    vertices[5] = 1.0f;     vertices[6] = -1.0f;    vertices[7] = 0.0f;     vertices[8] = 0.f;      vertices[9] = 1.f;
    vertices[10] = -1.0f;   vertices[11] = -1.0f;   vertices[12] = 0.0f;    vertices[13] = 1.f;    vertices[14] = 1.f;
    vertices[15] = -1.0f;   vertices[16] = 1.0f;    vertices[17] = 0.0f;    vertices[18] = 1.f;    vertices[19] = 0.f;

    // Setup indices
    indices[0] = 0; indices[1] = 1; indices[2] = 3;
    indices[3] = 1; indices[4] = 2; indices[5] = 3;

    // Setup buffers
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
}

static SDL_bool CompileShader(GLhandleARB shader, const char* source)
{
    GLint status = 0;

    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader);
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);

    if (status == 0)
    {
        GLint length = 0;
        char* info;

        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        info = (char*)SDL_malloc(length + 1);

        if (!info)
        {
            SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Out of memory!");
        }
        else
        {
            glGetInfoLogARB(shader, length, NULL, info);
            SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Failed to compile shader:\n%s\n%s", source, info);
            //SDL_free(info);
        }

        return SDL_FALSE;

    }
    else
        return SDL_TRUE;
}

static SDL_bool LinkProgram(ShaderData* data)
{
    GLint status = 0;

    glAttachShader(data->program, data->vert_shader);
    glAttachShader(data->program, data->frag_shader);
    glLinkProgram(data->program);

    glGetProgramiv(data->program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0)
    {
        GLint length = 0;
        char* info;

        glGetProgramiv(data->program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        info = (char*)SDL_malloc(length + 1);

        if (!info)
            SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Out of memory!");
        else
        {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(data->program, length, NULL, info);
            SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Failed to link program:\n%s", info);
            SDL_free(info);
        }

        return SDL_FALSE;

    }
    else
        return SDL_TRUE;
}

static SDL_bool CompileShaderProgram(ShaderData* data)
{
    const int num_tmus_bound = 4;
    int i;
    GLint location;

    glGetError();

    /* Create one program object to rule them all */
    data->program = glCreateProgram();

    /* Create the vertex shader */
    data->vert_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    if (!CompileShader(data->vert_shader, data->vert_source))
        return SDL_FALSE;

    /* Create the fragment shader */
    data->frag_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    if (!CompileShader(data->frag_shader, data->frag_source))
        return SDL_FALSE;

    /* ... and in the darkness bind them */
    if (!LinkProgram(data))
        return SDL_FALSE;

    return (glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR) ? SDL_TRUE : SDL_FALSE;
}

static void DestroyShaderProgram(ShaderData* data)
{
    glDeleteShader(data->vert_shader);
    glDeleteShader(data->frag_shader);
    glDeleteProgram(data->program);
}

/* Quick utility function for texture creation */
static int power_of_two(int input)
{
    int value = 1;

    while (value < input)
        value <<= 1;

    return value;
}

GLuint SDL_GL_LoadTexture(SDL_Surface* surface/*, GLfloat* texcoord*/)
{
    GLuint texture;
    int w, h;
    SDL_Surface* image;
    SDL_Rect area;
    SDL_BlendMode saved_mode;

    /* Use the surface width and height expanded to powers of 2 */
    w = power_of_two(surface->w);
    h = power_of_two(surface->h);

    image = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, w, h, 32,
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_LIL_ENDIAN     /* OpenGL RGBA masks */
        0x000000FF,
        0x0000FF00,
        0x00FF0000,
        0xFF000000
#else
        0xFF000000,
        0x00FF0000,
        0x0000FF00,
        0x000000FF
#endif
    );

    if (image == NULL)
        return 1;

    /* Save the alpha blending attributes */
    SDL_GetSurfaceBlendMode(surface, &saved_mode);
    SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(surface, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);

    /* Copy the surface into the GL texture image */
    area.x = 0;
    area.y = 0;
    area.w = surface->w;
    area.h = surface->h;
    SDL_BlitSurface(surface, &area, image, &area);

    /* Restore the alpha blending attributes */
    SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(surface, saved_mode);

    /* Create an OpenGL texture for the image */
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels);

    SDL_FreeSurface(image);     /* No longer needed */

    return texture;
}

static SDL_bool InitShaders()
{
    int i;

    /* Compile all the shaders */
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_SHADERS; ++i)
    {
        if (!CompileShaderProgram(&shaders[i]))
        {
            SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Unable to compile shader!\n");
            return SDL_FALSE;
        }
    }

    /* We're done! */
    return SDL_TRUE;
}

static void QuitShaders()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_SHADERS; ++i)
        DestroyShaderProgram(&shaders[i]);
}

void Run()
{
    bool shadersInitialised = InitShaders();
    if (!shadersInitialised)
        return;

    SetupDrawing();

    int texture = -1;
    SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_LoadBMP("icon.bmp");
    if (surface)
    {
        texture = SDL_GL_LoadTexture(surface);
    }

    int shaderIndex = 0;

    SDL_Event e;
    bool run = true;
    while (run)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))
        {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                run = false;
            }
            else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN & e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_SPACE)
            {
                if (shaderIndex == 0)
                {
                    shaderIndex = 1;
                }
                else if (shaderIndex == 1)
                {
                    shaderIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(shaders[shaderIndex].program);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        // Bind our vertices to our array
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        // Find our attributes in the current shader program and once found setup the 
        // attribute pointers
        int position = glGetAttribLocation(shaders[shaderIndex].program, "position");
        if (position != -1)
        {
            glVertexAttribPointer(position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
        }

        int textureCoord = glGetAttribLocation(shaders[shaderIndex].program, "texCoord");
        if (textureCoord != -1)
        {
            glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void *)(3 * sizeof(float)));
        }

        // Bind our indices to our array
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        // Enable vertex attrib array
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(position);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoord);

        // Draw
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // Disable vertex attrib array
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(position);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoord);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool setupSuccess = Setup();
    if (setupSuccess)
    {
        Run();
    }
    Teardown();
    return 0;
}
```